# Parity Blocked Chrome Extension

Tags: parity

I have Parity working remotely so that I can SSH to my Parity Host and load the UI from another computer. The chrome-extension however is not working...

In the Parity console window, I'm seeing this message over and over:

> Blocked connection from chrome-extension://himekenlppkgeaoeddcliojfddemadig using invalid token.

I'm forwarding ports 8180, 8545 and 8546 through the SSH tunnel in order to get my remote connection working. Is there something else I need to forward to get the chrome extension to work?

Thanks!